Can I define an alias for a git remote?
I have a git remote named foobar:
[remote "foobar"]
        url = git@github.com:joeuser/foobar.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/foobar/*

but I am also user to calling it foo-bar. I don't want to define foo-bar as a second remote - but I do want to used foo-bar and foobar interchangeably when referring to my single remote. Can I define foo-bar as an alias of foobar somehow?
Note: I realize that I if I add a second remote, git add remote foo-bar same_url_as_for_foobar, I would be able to use both names. The point is that I don't want to have to update/synch the branches on each copy of the remote.

Are you able to set the url of both remotes to be the same?

Do you mean foobar or foo-bar is remote? So you can use git command like git push foo-bar main, isn't it?

If it is what you mean, try git remote add foo-bar https://git.your.server/path/to/repo

@evolutionxbox: I am.

@AnthonyNguyen: That would clone the remote, not create an alias...

@einpoklum git remote add foo-bar doesn't clone the remote

this command git remote add foo-bar git remote add foo-bar https://git.your.server/path/to/repo adds new remote address at name foo-bar. It doesn't do anything else - no network data are exchanged. When you will do git fetch this adders will not do anything since this is second remote. You have to do git fetch --all or git fetch foobar to use this new remote address.

@MarekR: So, that's what I don't want. I want there to be a single remote, with both names referring to it.

If both names will use same address it will be close to "alias". The only problem is that remote branches names foobar/master foo-bar/master will be updated independently. When you do fetch on one name then using second name, git will notice there is no difference in commits and will not fetch anything extra. Same with push.  As I point out the only disadvantage is that you will have duplicated remote branch names (with different prefixes matching remote name).

"The only problem is that remote branches names foobar/master foo-bar/master will be updated independently" <- ... and getting around my problem is why I asked the question. Let me make this clearer in the question body.

It looks like a kind of an odd feature request I cannot find a use case for, pretty similar to something like "I've got two branches so they should be updated once of them changes just because they're local". Marek R is correct saying that they (branches) are independent so am I: these are independent pointers by design and implementation.

If you want two or more remotes update branches, I guess, git hooks is what you're looking for: all "remote aliases" update/sync magic would be wrapped in hook scripts: post-merge and post-push if I recall right, and post-commit hook: you'd need both detect "other" interchangeable remotes and git-update-ref accordingly. Would this play well on merge conflicts? As far as I understand, should do. Would this work for push/fetch? I guess so. Would this work for commits as well? I guess so. Git-reset? No idea. Maybe this also would require git-symbolic-ref to come into play.

"If you want two or more remotes update branches" <- I'm not sure if this is what I want... I mean, the remote repository does have multiple branches, but is that what you were describing? Also, I'm not talking about merging and pushing only, but even simply about things like git branch --remote which lists known branches.

@einpoklum Sorry I miscomposed the sentence. Now I'm not sure I even understand your question. The best way for me to understand it, I guess, would be seeing a preudo-input and -output for your "remote alias" and seeing describing the state of the refs in your repo. But not sure if it's worth doing it.
